# Entity Framework: String concat in database query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need to create a string concatenation with an linq statement. I have the following data:

**Section**

- Id: 1, Title: Test1
- Id: 2, Title: Test2

**Section_User**

- SectionId: 1, UserId: 1
- SectionId: 1, UserId: 2

**Users**

- Id: 1, Name: User1
- Id: 2, Name: User2

**I need the following result:**

SectionId: 1, Users: User1, User2

I create the following Linq statement:

```
var query2 =    from section in this.context.Sections
                from users in section.Users
                group section by section2.Id into groupedSection
                select new {
                    SectionId = groupedSection.Key,
                    Users = string.Join(",", users.Select (x => x.Name)) // compile error, but I don't know how I write the statement correctly
                };
```

Could someone tell me, how I can create a string concatenation on database side (not in-memory) with an linq statement.

Thanks!!

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428175/2780791).

Comment: You can use `string.format` instead of join.

Comment: I don't think it's supported by EF. So unfortunately the answer is - you can't.

Comment: With EF you'll always have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18826711/861716).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Alexei 's link in the comments, your line should look like

```
var query2 =    from section in this.context.Sections
                from users in section.Users
                group section by section2.Id into groupedSection
                select new {
                    SectionId = groupedSection.Key,
                    Users = string.Join(",", (from u in users select s.Name).ToArray())
                };
```

However, if that doesn't work due to LINQ to Entities error, and you're willing to simply leave `Users` as an `IEnumerable<string>`, you can simply use:

```
var query2 =    from section in this.context.Sections
                from users in section.Users
                group section by section2.Id into groupedSection
                select new {
                    SectionId = groupedSection.Key,
                    Users = (from u in users select s.Name)
                };
```

And later whenever needed, you can join the strings, or display the names using a loop.

Comment: The answer form Alexei's link does not work for me. Fo this I wrote the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753791/2489386

Comment: I've searched for some time now, and there does not seem to by any way for your concat/join operation without `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()`, the closest thing I could think of would be to write a pure MySQL statement and execute it using [Raw SQL queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx).